# Process thermal data in R

Tags: r

I have tried to make a thermal simulation with R; In which I should try to make process inside series. for example I should run this process several times:

```
 T[i,j]=.25*(T[i+1,j]+T[i,j+1]+T[i-1,j]+T[i,j-1])
```

I know how to make such a thing in C or FORTRAN but still this is unclear for me in R.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let T be 10*10 array. The iteration is:

```
T[2:9,2:9] <- (T[1:8,2:9] + T[3:10,2:9] + T[2:9,1:8] + T[2:9,3:10]) / 4
- and similar for edges
```